# Upgrading from 16.04 to 16.10 on HP Notebook 2000

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation

Tried to upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to 16.10 on a HP Notebook 2000. The upgrade went very badly. I could login, but I received a completely black screen with a message saying internal error. I downloaded a copy of 16.10 and am trying to repair or salvage the laptop. However, when I try to install over my old version and save my data, I get a message saying there is no /boot partition. Yet there is an option to Go Back which will allow me to edit my partitions, and there I clearly see /sda1 listed as /boot and /efi. I cannot complete the install without the /boot partition being recognized. 
Any suggestions of what to do next?

Comment: is this a UEFI machine?

Comment: Yes. It is UEFI.